# Matlab script does not evaluate valid if construction

Tags: matlab, if-statement, floating-point, comparison

I have a 2D point `vectorA` and a rectangle with boundaries `vectorX` and `vectorY`. Following MWE represents my MATLAB code to check whether the point lies on the four consecutive boundaries:

```
vectorA=[1.6667 2];
vectorX=[0 1.6667];
vectorY=[2 3.3333]
if vectorA(1)==vectorX(1)
    disp('XL')
end
if vectorA(1)==vectorX(2)
    disp('XU')
end
if vectorA(2)==vectorY(1)
    disp('YL')
end
if vectorA(2)==vectorY(2)
    disp('YU')
end
```

I encountered a case for which the function did not detect that a given coordinate lied on a boundary. I printed the internal values of the variables and although I had `if 1.6667==1.6667`, that `if` was not evaluated.

Manually executing the consecutive calculations of my script works fine (including `1.6667==1.6667` which yields `1`), but executing the script gives a wrong result. Where can I search for the reason for this strange behaviour?

Comment: Probably an issue of floating point precision, take a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, most possibly, lies in the visual representation of numbers.

I mean that you **see** that the value is `1.6667` but the value (probably) is `1.666641239012783482983742987` (just random typing).

To play around with representations, check the `format` command. Start by typing in command window `format long e` and check again.

Comment: This might be suitable for some cases, but is no reliable method. For example `x=0.1+0.1+0.1;
y=0.3;
x==y` Both values look the same using the format, but they are not. I recommend to take the difference for debugging purposes instead. `x-y`

Comment: Yeap... also a nice method for such cases!

Comment: This was indeed the problem. I replaced `if x==y` by `if abs(x-y)<eps` with `eps=0.0001` for `format short`.